# Push Notification not showing in iOS 10

Tags: swift, firebase, ios10

How can I get notification in iOS 10? In previous version, I can receive notification in     `func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])`.

In iOS 10, Apple introduces `UNNotificationSettings`. I can get FCM with `func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage)`.

However, I cannot get notification showing up on my phone in the background.

[image]

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
            authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }


    return true
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate {
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)

}


// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps at all, but in iOS 10 some new requirements were added that meant I had to check compabilities screen, it shown a warning for me under push notifications that I had to add an entitlements file with the property: `APS Environment  = development`. Do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: Yes, it already is. Also, I do not get any errors or warnings. Just no notifications showing up.

Comment: is register deviceToken for iOS10?

Comment: add application.registerForRemoteNotifications() after iOS10 Notifications

Comment: I have the same issue, even though application.registerForRemoteNotifications() is outside else {..}
I can receive push notifications when I'm sending them from Firebase Console or any other APN, but not when I'm sending it as a POST on https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send . When I'm sending it via POST I can see them in xCode console but not able to show them as alert notification (even with priority = "high")

Comment: Restart your device and try the push notification again, I hope you will get the notifications then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to move this method

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

to above return statement.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)
-> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
            authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)        
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)

    return true
 }
```