# FirebasePush Notifications are only displayed in the console and don't load in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I prepared all certificates, uploaded them to the Firebase console, updated my App ID and the settings in my Xcode project. However my app can't display any push notifications. If I send a push notification from the Firebase console I only see the message in the console while running my app not in background mode. I use a real device/iPhone 6S.

Besides that the console is showing me the following error if I comment all the disconnect part from the AppDelegate.

```
Unable to connect with FCM. Optional(Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "(null)")
```

I prepared Firebase Push Notifications in the AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseRemoteConfig

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        FIRApp.configure()
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

        //let _ = RemoteConfigValues.sharedInstance

        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)
        logUser()

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
        var tokenString = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
            tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
        }

        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)

        print("tokenString: \(tokenString)")
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"])")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        connectToFcm()
    }

    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]


}
```

Comment: Add priority key to High in the notification and try

Comment: What do you mean? The priority key in Firebase? I did that and it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced this error ,when i changed the notification data that is being sent to the Following ,it worked for me

{"to":"coYbqscbjkA,S","priority" : "high"
 "notification":{"body":"12345 ","service_type":"My Service"}}

Check Once...Hope it works...!

Comment: But how should I change the notification? I get the notification from Firebase to the console but only if the app is active. I want Push Notifications in background mode.

Comment: Are you getting notifications when app is in   foreground...?

Comment: Yes but only in the console. I don't see an alert or push notification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914557/push-notification-not-showing-in-ios-10 check this

Comment: No sadly not. The statement already was above the return statement.